# MassTransit Multiple Consumers All Receive Same Message in different name spaces?

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

```
Environment:
 Three Projects (one publisher and three subscribers):
   consoleConsumer1
   consoleConsumer2
   consolePublisher1
```

The publisher send the message through the publishendpoint in consolePublisher1 namespace

```
_publishEndPoint.Publish<ManagerCreated>()
```

And I have two other projects, surely with two different namespaces that accidentally have the same consumer name for handing ManagerCreated Event so normally i have added this consumer

```
    mt.AddConsumer<ManagerChangedIntegrationEventHandler>();
```

i would expect that masstransit creates two fanout exchanges and queues with names like these

```
consoleConsumer1:ManagerChangedIntegrationEventHandler
and
consoleConsumer2:ManagerChangedIntegrationEventHandler
```

but it only creates one fanout exchange named:

```
ManagerChangedIntegrationEventHandler
```

which these two consumers compete to consume messages. I know I can create queue endpoint so that an exchange publishes the message to two different queues but is there any way that this happen by convention?

and why shouldn't project name or namespace effect the exchange and queue name?

what is the best way of using namespaces in consumers registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [an issue](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/2030) already created for this, and the ability to include the namespace using any of the endpoint name formatters will be available in the next release.

Comment: thanks a lot what is the best approach for now? what is the clean way?

Comment: For now? You could copy the code in that commit to have your own endpoint name formatter in your project.

Comment: thank you again it would be nice to see best pattern and practices at twitch live coding